Request community attention to reopen question
This question was recently closed very quickly.
It was not closed quickly enough to prevent one very proficient user from posting a quality answer demonstrating two approaches, with extra considerations and reference to "work to be done."
The OP's intent is demonstrably comprehensible requiring no "mind reading." The neophyte's description reflects a beginner's attempt to describe a problem. The question's title is a clear expression of the objective, although one more fluent in English may have written "tally", rather than "count".
One close vote came from a user who admitted, in a now-deleted comment, to have "not noticed that part of the OP's problem statement." (my paraphrased recollection of that comment.)
One close vote came from a user whose actions (write-an-answer or vote-to-close based on the presence/absence of an MRE) can be shown to be inconsistent.
One close vote came from a user who, in now-purged discussion via comments, effectively stated that the English phrase "count from" is subject-to-interpretation (i.e. whether a starting point is included or excluded from the tally.) (imo) "count upwards from 10" means only that '10' is included in the count.
After some days, I attempted to "improve" the question by minimally improving its content, making some of its phrases bold, and clarifying the OP's example results by adding the explanatory terms "even values" and "odd values" appropriately. This attempt was "rolled back" with a note about "performing mind reading interpretation of OP's intent".
(imo) a reasonable person, making allowances for a beginner's lexicon and conceptualisation, should have little trouble understanding this original question.
It's my feeling that this particular question, and the reaction of the entire SO community's 3 representatives, could be a case study on the concerning topic of diminishing interest in SO as a resource for beginners.
Thank you for your attention.

Clarification:
In pursuit of transparency, my interest in having the OP's question re-opened is to present the beginner with a possible solution that only involves a single function being coded.
"Less (correct & comprehensible) code is better code."

So why are those users who voted to close the question not voting to reopen the question? The minute I make a mistake with regards to voting to close a question, I retract it or vote to reopen the question, are these users not familiar with SO? 6 users so far have voted to close the question or voted to keep it closed. One of those users were a moderator. (I know the answer to the question I proposed by the way).

@SecurityHound The "close voters" have 5 & 6 digit rep. The conundrum is that too many examples can be found of "unpredictable" actions taken by users. One hi-rep user responded to another "deficient" question, ignoring the OP's sample input values and using fabricated values to demonstrate their expertise and guru-like familiarity with documentation. (Again, I don't mean to disparage technical prowess of some.) Seeking a steady-not-erratic hand on the tiller... "Consistent rules for the game being played..."

The largest issue here appears to be that this is not a debugging question (it is a how-to question), yet it received 3 close votes for "Needs debugging details"...  I suspect this is likely to be a duplicate, though I can't immediately find one (note: I spent very little time looking).  I do agree that it's not really clear whether or not the specified index is included (your example of "count upwards from 10" is much clearer than the phrasing in context), though that could be addressed in a good answer (by giving both options) because it doesn't fundamentally change the solution. [cont'd]

It's also worth noting, as a comment does, that the standard definitions of "left" and "right" are called into question by the example code (though again, an answer could address this). Ultimately, I'm not voting to reopen because it's not completely clear (and as a mod, my votes are binding), but I found the question clear enough to be answerable, so I wouldn't have voted to close, either.

If purpose of the question is to get generic approach about bits counting, then given question could be a possible "duplicate" candidate. If purpose of the question is to fix provided code, then "debugging details" are definitely not complete: there is no output (neither expected nor actual), there is no attempt to determine (e.g. with printf) which exact bit is classified incorrectly. In both cases I see a little value in the question. Why bother to reopen it?

@Tsyvarev How is counting the bits to one side of a specified position a duplicate of counting all the bits?

@Tsyvarev I'm chuckling over the scenario of sending a "newbie" to find the answer to their predicament somewhere in the Babel-like tome of your linked "wiki Q&A". Even experienced users would fear to tread through that morass of (often repetitious) "helpful" solutions... This beginner does not seek to tally ALL the bits of a variable, but has, to my mind, a clear, specific objective not covered in that Q&A. I agree with 'RyanM' that this neophyte question has merit. We all have opinions, thus THIS "canvassing question" has been posted to Meta...

@RyanM in the same way that "how do I write a loop to count numbers from y to x" would be a duplicate of "how do I write a loop to count numbers from 1 to x". Being able to accommodate the additional restriction is a necessary consequence of understanding the more simply stated version of the question. Aside from approaches that loop over the bits (which could pick a different start point), approaches that "directly" count bits by bit twiddling hacks could simply mask the desired part of the input first.

@KarlKnechtel "... could simply mask ..." Sure. However, that may not occur to a beginner, and "Do not post answers in comments." prohibits conveying that helpful 'tip' to the OP (or anyone else, in the future, who might face a similar problem.) 'Tsyvarev's linked Q&A is full of alternative answers to its specific problem that is not the particular problem of the OP of the question I'm suggesting be re-opened.

@RyanM: I think it is a debugging question. If the attempt and half-finished debugging details were edited out of the question, it could be reasonably answered with the code that’s currently in the question (but also with some variation of popcount(x >> i) and popcount(x << (63 - i)) for uint64_t x, which is what I was getting ready to answer with when I realized that). (And even a “how do I” would benefit greatly from clarifying the off-by-one and left vs. right issues with a simple complete example input and output.)

@KarlKnechtel By that standard, "count how many bits are set" is a duplicate of "check if a specific bit is set", because you could simply do so in a loop. That's not at all not how duplicates are supposed to work. A few reasons for that: 1) nontrivial additional work (here, the idea to use a mask) is part of the answer (it didn't occur to me, because I don't really work with bit twiddling in that way).  Additionally, generating that mask is not exactly trivial; I'd need to look up how to do it, and there's probably some clever sign extension trick or something to do it efficiently. [cont'd]


Even ignoring that, just because a different question provides one way to solve the problem does not mean that that is the only or best way to solve it.  As an extreme (non-programming) example, "How do I uninstall [antivirus software]?" is not a duplicate of "How do I reinstall Windows from scratch?", even though doing the latter will accomplish the former.  There are likely ways to do the former without doing the latter, and closing as duplicate forecloses those useful answers (such as the top answer on the "count all set bits" question, which provides a loop-free approach).


The question is OK, it just needed a little bit of critical clarification which was not forthcoming from the OP. And I suspect that if the clarification would've been provided then the question would've been closed as a duplicate, which is an expected and not-at-all-bad outcome.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I've recently stepped up my game by trying, not one but several terms in the "Search" box. To my joy, I discovered using 3 (blindly obvious!) search terms returned 1 ancient answer (13 years old on this weekend) that precisely addressed the same problem as was expressed in another Q posed just 10 days ago. (mea culpa! I'm not a "power user" here on SO.) Apart registering my lonely VTC on this most-recent Q, how can I encourage others to "take another look" at this obvious duplicate Q (aging fast) as they have toward the now-purged SO Q that started this whole thing?

My conclusions from reading the question:

OP has not actually asked a question at all. The post simply describes an intended task and then makes a claim that an existing attempt "fails" in certain circumstances.

To the extent that a question can be inferred, it is clearly seeking debugging help, and not asking how to do something. The OP shows a fundamentally valid approach to solving the described problem (loop and shift); while it may not be the most performant, no interest is shown in alternate approaches.

Treated as a "debugging question", the question clearly does not meet standards:

Aside from an imprecise description of the circumstances when the code "fails" (imprecise enough that you tried to edit it and someone else disagreed with your interpretation of the meaning), it does not even attempt to describe what this "failure" entails (A wrong answer? A crash? Something else?). As an aside, I agree that recasting "ends with 1/0 in binary" as "odd/even" is legitimate, but your interpretation of whether "to the left" or "to the right" is inclusive or exclusive is not appropriate.

It also doesn't attempt to explain whether the value chosen for position has any influence on whether the code "fails" - which would seem rather important.

Finally, it seems that the code interprets "to the left" as meaning less significant bits (since this loop counts up to position), which is the opposite of how numbers are ordinarily conceived of in place-value arithmetic (although it could make sense if one is thinking in terms of memory layout and assuming little-endian values). So in this sense it is again unclear. (If OP meant that "to the left" should refer to the more significant bits, but wrote a loop to examine less significant bits, then this is either again a typo, or a complete failure to understand place-value arithmetic in a way that can't reasonably be addressed here.)



Regardless of the interpretation, it's trivial to understand what is wrong with the code (if indeed there is anything wrong) after actually examining the behaviour of the code and looking for any kind of pattern in the failures (assuming that they are indeed simply wrong answers; I am not set up to test, but I see no reason for the given code to crash). The offered answer, before going off about a completely (unnecessarily) different implementation, can only suggest a possible off-by-one error, and is only making such a suggestion because of the overall lack of clarity. (Signed arithmetic cannot reasonably be blamed here, because only positive inputs are discussed, which would behave the same way with signed and unsigned types.)

In short: OP does not clearly describe a problem; OP does not clearly ask about a problem; to the extent that a problem is described, it isn't clear that a problem actually occurs (and especially not that such a problem actually depends on the parity of the input; and to the extent that a problem occurs, it is certainly caused by a typo (an off-by-one error, i.e. an idiosyncratic logical failure). As such, the question should remain closed.



Aside from that: even if this were recast as a how-to question, it would require a sufficiently precise specification to be considered, along with a proper explanation of why there is any difficulty. Aside from that, I tend to agree with the analysis that this could be considered a duplicate. Standard bit-counting techniques can be used in combination with masking to count bits to the left or right of a specified point; anyone who needs more sophisticated techniques than naively looping over bits, would certainly be able to adapt the technique. We surely do not need to explain that "how to count all the bits" can be adapted to answer "how to count the bits in this region" by first isolating the region in question. (If someone doesn't know how to do such isolation, that is a separate question that also has separate answers.)
The fact that a reference Q&A might be overly lengthy or discuss techniques beyond a beginner's ken is not a reason to ignore duplicates. It is a reason to improve existing answers, offer bounties for better answers that explain the material from a more basic perspective, and try to get redundant answers deleted.

Other issues with the question aside, the claim that describing an intended task is not asking a question is problematic, especially given the number of comments people post complaining about the lack of an attempt.  This is a game askers cannot win: either they leave out the attempt because it's irrelevant for a how-to question, and are scolded and downvoted for that, or they post their attempt and have it cast as an bad debugging question (when they care less about debugging their own code than just solving the problem).  The question is implied: "how do I do the task I just described?"

@Ðаո Sorry, I'm not sure how that disagrees with anything I said.  Of course people manage to ask acceptable questions.  My statement is simply that a lack of a sentence ending in a question mark does not make a question any less acceptable, as long as it nonetheless clearly describes a well-scoped programming task.

"This is a game askers cannot win: either they leave out the attempt because it's irrelevant for a how-to question, and are scolded and downvoted for that, or they post their attempt and have it cast as an bad debugging question" - no, not at all. They can, and should: 1) choose whether it is a how-to question or a what's-wrong question; 2a) in the former case, give a clear specification for the expected behaviour (sufficient to cover reasonably foreseeable edge cases); 2b) in the latter case, give an MRE and a clear description of actual and expected behaviour; 3) also ask a question.

To be explicit: by "ask a question" I really do literally mean "write a sentence in the body of the post (not only the title) which starts with a question word like 'why' or 'how' and ends with a ? symbol". This is not required, but it very often improves clarity.

"My statement is simply that a lack of a sentence ending in a question mark does not make a question any less acceptable, as long as it nonetheless clearly describes a well-scoped programming task." In that case, I don't understand the supposed dilemma. Nothing about posting a specification or an MRE prevents the inclusion of such a sentence.
